# Como tocar audio em fila no SDL MIxer e C++?

Tags: c++, áudio, sdl

Tenho 4 áudios diferentes; quero tocá-los em fila, apertar um botão e tocar o 1; quando acabar de tocar automaticamente ele começar a tocar o 2, depois o 3 e depois o 4.... é possível fazer isso no SDL Mixer?

Eu só consegui através do `while`, porém, quando entra nele tudo pára, ele interrompe as outras funções... também tentei através das tarefas do Thread.Join.... mas ai é que está, o Join não sabe que a tarefa 1 terminou.... tem que haver um meio do C++ entender que a tarefa foi finalizada; mas acho que ele não reconhece porque o método é de uma biblioteca externa....

```
void tarefa1()
{
    Mix_PlayChannel(1, som_1, 0);

}

void tarefa2()
{
    Mix_PlayChannel(1, som_2, 0);
}

void tocar() {

    thread first(tarefa1);
    thread second(tarefa2);

    first.join();   
    second.join(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo, um detalhe: pela descriçaõ do seu problema, o tipo `Mix_Music*` me parece mais apropriado do que o tipo `Mix_Chunk*`. De todo o modo, vou responder a pergunta tomando como base o tipo `Mix_Chunk*`.

Quanto ao uso de `std::thread`, ele me parece desnecessário, pois a função `Mix_PlayChannel` já executa a música em uma thread separada. Então, O que você poderia fazer é usar a função `Mix_Playing()` para saber se uma música está sendo tocada ou não e variáveis para controlar qual música está sendo tocada, qual é a próxima, etc.

Eu fiz uma função para realizar esta tarefa, chamada de `Player()` e como eu queria testar preparei a função `main()` também. Coloco ambas abaixo, pois acho que facilita para você entender o que foi feito:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>

void Player(Mix_Chunk* mMusic[])
{
    static int previous = 0;
    static int current = 0;

    if (current < 4) {
        if (previous == current) {
            std::cout << "Tocando musica n. " << current + 1 << '\n';
            Mix_PlayChannel(-1, mMusic[current], 1);
            current++;
        }
        if (!Mix_Playing(-1)) {
            previous = current;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        960, 540, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window) { return -1; }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 50, 50, 50, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //Initialize SDL_mixer
    Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048);

    //The music that will be played
    Mix_Chunk *gMusic = Mix_LoadWAV("beat.wav");
    Mix_Chunk* mMusic[4] = { gMusic, gMusic, gMusic, gMusic };
    SDL_Event e;

    int previous = 1;
    int current = 1;


    while (true) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {

            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                return 0;
            }           
        }

        Player(mMusic);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }   

    //Free the music
    Mix_FreeChunk(gMusic);
    gMusic = NULL;

    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    renderer = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    Mix_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, V. Santos. Obrigado, eu vou testar aqui e volto  postar pra saber se deu certo... É que na verdade, eu uso um formulário - Win Form... e colocando qualquer tipo de while o formulário travava, não respondia aos comandos. Na verdade eu resolvi colocando o áudio numa thread e usando o detach() ao invés do Join... a thread executa realmente em paralelo e as outras coisa do programa continuam respondendo... mas eu vou testar sua sugestão. Se der certo, melhor que eu não preciso usar threads...